# Class Error Vertical Panel--Google Apps

Tags: google-apps-script

I am getting a class error when I add a vertical panel to my widget and cannot seem to find why. Can you even add a vertical panel to a widget? Or is there maybe another way I can add to the Name and Attribute Labels outside of a Vertical Panel?

```
maxImgs = 6;      // Number of images in grid
colUrl = 45;       // Column containing URL
colName = 48;      // Column containing Name
colAttr = 46;      // Column containing Attributes



function doGet(e) {
var app= UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('Not Here')  
var abspanel= app.createAbsolutePanel();//.setHeight('100%').setWidth('100%');
var stackpanel=app.createStackPanel();
var grid = app.createGrid(8,8);

var titleLabel= app.createLabel('Not Here');
titleLabel.setStyleAttribute("text-align", "center");
titleLabel.setStyleAttribute("font-size", "135%");
titleLabel.setStyleAttribute("font-weight", "bold");
var insertlabel= app.createLabel('Which Schedule? (Insert Document Key)');
var inserttxtbox=app.createTextBox().setId('txtbox').setName('ttbox').setMaxLength(44);
var loadbtn= app.createButton('Load Pictures').setId('loadbtn');
var resetbtn= app.createButton('Refresh').setId('rbtn').setVisible(false);
var daylabel= app.createLabel('Select Day');
var mon= "P - Mon"
var tues= "P - Tues"
var wed= "P - Wed"
var thurs= "P - Thurs"
var fri= "P - Fri"
var dayListBox= app.createListBox().setWidth('140px').setId('day').setName ('sday')
dayListBox.addItem(mon);
dayListBox.addItem(tues);
dayListBox.addItem(wed);
dayListBox.addItem(thurs);
dayListBox.addItem(fri); 
var spinner= app.createImage('http://www.zho.ae/_layouts/ZHO/AR/Images/loader_spinner.gif').setVisible(false).setId('spinner');
var loadSpinner = app.createClientHandler()
              .forTargets(spinner)
              .setVisible(true);
 loadbtn.addClickHandler(loadSpinner);


 var loadhandler=app.createServerHandler('loadPics');
 loadhandler.addCallbackElement(stackpanel);
 loadbtn.addClickHandler(loadhandler);

 grid
.setWidget(1,0,insertlabel)
.setWidget(1,1,inserttxtbox)
.setWidget(2,0, daylabel)
.setWidget(2,1, dayListBox)
.setWidget(3,1, loadbtn)
.setWidget(3,2,resetbtn)
.setWidget(4,2,spinner)


var image = [];
for (var img = 0, row = 5; img < maxImgs; img++) {
image[img] = app.createImage().setPixelSize(250, 250).setId('image' + img).setVisible(false);
var imageName = app.createLabel().setId('name'+img).setVisible(false);
var imageAttr = app.createLabel().setId('attr'+img).setVisible(false);
var vertPan = app.createVerticalPanel().add(imageName).add(imageAttr).add(image);
grid.setWidget(row + Math.floor(img / 3), 1 + (img % 3), vertPan);
}


abspanel.add(titleLabel);
stackpanel.add(grid);
app.add(abspanel);
app.add(stackpanel);

return app;
}


function loadPics(e){
var app= UiApp.getActiveApplication();
var ss= SpreadsheetApp.openById(e.parameter.ttbox);
var list=ss.getSheetByName(e.parameter.sday);
var data = list.getDataRange().getValues().splice(1); // Get whole spreadsheet, without headers
// In this example, URLs are in A, Name in B, Attributes in C

for (var row = 0, img = 0; row < data.length && img < maxImgs; row++) {
var rowData = data[row];
if (rowData[colUrl] != '') {
  var image = app.getElementById('image' + img);
  var imageName = app.getElementById('name'+img);
  var imageAttr = app.getElementById('attr'+img);
        image.setUrl(rowData[colUrl])
       .setTitle(rowData[colName].toString() === '' ? 'image'+img : rowData[colName])
       .setVisible(true);
  imageName.setText(rowData[colName])
       .setVisible(true);
  imageAttr.setText(rowData[colAttr])
       .setVisible(true);
  img++;

 }
}


app.getElementById('spinner').setVisible(false);

return app;  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error doesn't come from the vertical panel... You're adding `image` which is an array of widgets, not a UiApp widget.

Try to add array elements in a for loop instead, something like

```
var vertPan = app.createVerticalPanel().add(imageName).add(imageAttr);
  for(var n in image){vertPan.add(image[n])};
```

EDIT : I re-read [Mogsdad's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17976520/create-array-of-images-google-script) on your other post and his code was different... you won't get that nice grid result with this version of the code ... I 'm not sure I understand why you created that array ???

EDIT2 : just for testing I tried Mogsdad's code with this slight modification to see how it shows up ...

```
  for (var img = 0, row = 5; img < maxImgs; img++) {
    var image = app.createImage().setPixelSize(250, 250).setId('image' + img).setVisible(true);
    var imageName = app.createLabel('name').setId('name'+img).setVisible(true);
    var imageAttr = app.createLabel('attr').setId('attr'+img).setVisible(true);
    var vertPan = app.createVerticalPanel().add(imageName).add(imageAttr).add(image);
    grid.setWidget(row + Math.floor(img / 3), 1 + (img % 3), vertPan)
  }
```

and I get this :
[image]

---

**EDIT 3 :** here is a modified verion of Mogsdad's code that should allow you to see more easily what is going on and is in a 2x2 matrix with visible (and colored) panels...

```
maxImgs = 4;      // Number of images in grid
colUrl = 3;       // Column containing URL
colName = 0;      // Column containing Name
colAttr = 1;      // Column containing Attributes

function doGet(e) {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('Not Here');
  var abspanel = app.createAbsolutePanel().setStyleAttribute('padding','25px');
  var grid = app.createGrid(8, 8);

  var titleLabel = app.createLabel('Not Here');
  titleLabel.setStyleAttribute('margin-left','85px');
  titleLabel.setStyleAttribute("font-size", "135%");
  titleLabel.setStyleAttribute("font-weight", "bold");
  var insertlabel = app.createLabel('Which Schedule? (Insert Document Key)');
  var inserttxtbox = app.createTextBox().setId('txtbox').setName('ttbox').setMaxLength(44);
  var loadbtn = app.createButton('Load Pictures').setId('loadbtn');
  var resetbtn = app.createButton('Refresh').setId('rbtn').setVisible(false);
  var daylabel = app.createLabel('Select Day');
  var mon = "P - Mon"
  var tues = "P - Tues"
  var wed = "P - Wed"
  var thurs = "P - Thurs"
  var fri = "P - Fri"
  var dayListBox = app.createListBox().setWidth('140px').setId('day').setName('sday')
  dayListBox.addItem(mon);
  dayListBox.addItem(tues);
  dayListBox.addItem(wed);
  dayListBox.addItem(thurs);
  dayListBox.addItem(fri);

  // Borrowed from https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/learn-by-example/uiapp-examples-code-snippets/progress-indicators
  var spinner = app.createImage('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/211279/loading3T.gif')
                                .setVisible(false)
                                .setId('spinner');
  // Client handler for loadbtn will start spinner when button clicked
  // Server handler will stop spinner when done loading pictures
  var loadSpinner = app.createClientHandler()
                  .forTargets(spinner)
                  .setVisible(true);
  loadbtn.addClickHandler(loadSpinner);  

  var loadhandler = app.createServerHandler('loadPics');
  loadhandler.addCallbackElement(abspanel);
  loadbtn.addClickHandler(loadhandler);

  grid
    .setWidget(1, 0, insertlabel)
    .setWidget(1, 1, inserttxtbox)
    .setWidget(2, 0, daylabel)
    .setWidget(2, 1, dayListBox)
    .setWidget(3, 1, loadbtn)
    .setWidget(3, 2, resetbtn)
    .setWidget(2, 2, spinner)
    .setCellSpacing(5);

  for (var img = 0, row = 5; img < maxImgs; img++) {
    var image = app.createImage().setPixelSize(250, 250).setId('image' + img);
    var imageName = app.createLabel('name').setId('name'+img);
    var imageAttr = app.createLabel('attr').setId('attr'+img);
    var vertPan = app.createVerticalPanel().add(imageName).add(imageAttr).add(image).setStyleAttributes({'padding':'15px','borderStyle':'solid','border-radius':'15px','background':'silver'}).setVisible(false).setId('vertPanel'+img);
    grid.setWidget(row + Math.floor(img / 2), 1 + (img % 2), vertPan)
  }
  abspanel.add(titleLabel);
  abspanel.add(grid);
  app.add(abspanel);

  return app;
}


function loadPics(e) {
    e = {};
    e.parameter = {};
    e.parameter.ttbox = '0AnqSFd3iikE3dGFsUWNpb08zVWx5YjFRckloZ0NFZGc'
    e.parameter.sday = 'Sheet1'
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(e.parameter.ttbox);
  var list = ss.getSheetByName(e.parameter.sday);
  var data = list.getDataRange().getValues().splice(1); // Get whole spreadsheet, without headers

  for (var row = 0, img = 0; row < data.length && img < maxImgs; row++) {
    var rowData = data[row];
    if (rowData[0] != '') {
      var image = app.getElementById('image' + img);
      var imageName = app.getElementById('name'+img);
      var imageAttr = app.getElementById('attr'+img);
      var vertPan = app.getElementById('vertPanel'+img).setVisible(true);
      image.setUrl(rowData[colUrl])
           .setTitle(rowData[colName].toString() === '' ? 'image'+img : rowData[colName]);
      imageName.setText(rowData[colName]);
      imageAttr.setText(rowData[colAttr]);
      img++;
    }
  }

  // Done loading, hide spinner
  app.getElementById('spinner').setVisible(false);
  return app;
}
```

SS [viewable here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AnqSFd3iikE3dGFsUWNpb08zVWx5YjFRckloZ0NFZGc&usp=sharing)

demo [app available here](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbx-fjWmFvSDkHAbbl8Q1V__uF7meDjDO7NhQa4nK1304qA9egU/exec)

You can see that labels correspond to images (only 4 first links are used)

Comment: So I modified my code with: var vertPan = app.createVerticalPanel().add(imageName).add(imageAttr);
  for(var n in image){vertPan.add(image[n])};
But the pictures are stack on top of one another. They are offset and the labels do not belong to the corresponding picture. Is this maybe something in the loop formula?

Comment: That's why I edited my answer... why did you add this array?  The original code from Mogsdad works nicely...

Comment: It works for the pictures but not for the name and attribute. That is why he suggested adding a vertical panel as a widget to display name and attribute above the picture. But I get the Class Error before anything loads up.

Comment: When I tried it it shows both labels at their place... could you describe the issue you had?

Comment: Label                  Label      Picture                                                             Picture                                                              So I get two labels and the pictures right under the second label one on top of the other

Comment: And what exactly would you like to get?

Comment: So I get two labels and the pictures right under the second label one on top of the other. The picture corresponding to the first label is under the second. And the second picture is right under that picture. so instead of being 2 by 2 grid I get a 2 by 3 grid. I want the picture to be right under the corresponding label.

Comment: maxImgs = 6;      // Number of images in grid
colUrl = 45;       // Column containing URL
colName = 48;      // Column containing Name
colAttr = 46;      // Column containing Attributes

Comment: I added this with different values for the columns but no URL loads up.

Comment: I also took this off:     //e = {};
    //e.parameter = {};
    //e.parameter.ttbox = '0AnqSFd3iikE3dGFsUWNpb08zVWx5YjFRckloZ0NFZGc'
    //e.parameter.sday = 'Sheet1'

Comment: Because the id and the sheet values come from the textbox and the dropdown widgets.

Comment: Did you take into account that column numbers must be counted from 0 because they refer to arrays index.?  Forgive me if it's a silly question but I can't see any other reason this doesn't work :-)

Comment: Ok I see why. I have IF statements in the cells in those columns? Any idea why it does not like that and in Mogsdad code it did?